# How to find Deadlock using NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, deadlock

I have a rare issue when my Java application freezes. Now I was able to reproduce it in debug mode in NetBeans. So it currently stays frozen, but I don't know how to find where exactly in the code it has the deadlock, and in which threads. The callstack window is empty, the threads screenshot is attached.
What should I do to find the problem in the code?

[image]

Comment: You should take a few consecutive thread dumps, then you can compare them and see where your threads are waiting - there is your dead lock

Comment: And how to create these thread dumps?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html or `kill -3 PID` on linux is also an option

Comment: @SvetlinZarev, Thanks. If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to locate the deadlock you have to take a few consecutive thread dumps. And when you compare them you will see where the treads are waiting - this is your dead lock.

You can use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) (which should be part of your JDK installation) to take thread dumps or alternatively if you use Linux you can use `kill -3 PID`

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans invoke "Debug->Check for Deadlock" (menu bar)